# Append Strategy on field in Mongodb Document through kafka sink connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

first stream of kafka insert Document in Mongodb. second independent stream will update single field in existing Document in Mongodb.

what strategy /transformation we have to use for it , how we configure our kafka mongo sink connector ?

Comment: I don't think the sink connectors support partial updates. The whole record is added or updated

Comment: @cricket_007 So what strategy can be used to update a whole record?